# Updating dropdown from redux state in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm a beginner in react-redux. I've implemented the dependant dropdown functionality in react component.(Country => State => City).

I want to update dropdown values when I receive data from redux state.

I am getting redux state in `this.props.dropdownForm` and based on that calling `changeCountry`, `changeState`, `changeCity` functions where I'm setting the selected country based on condition.

What problem I'm facing is this piece of code is not working:

```
componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.dropdownForm) {
            this.changeCountry();
            this.changeState();
            // this.changeCity();
        }
    }
```

but when I put above code in setTimeout then it works updates the country dropdown

```
componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.props.dropdownForm) {
                this.changeCountry();
                this.changeState();
                // this.changeCity();
            }
        }, 100);    
    }
```

but that too is not consistent, means sometime it works sometime it doesn't.

Not getting this weird behaviour.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Col, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { getDropdownData } from '../../redux/profile/profile.selectors';

class Dropdown extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            countries: [
                { name: 'Germany', states: [{ name: 'A', cities: ['Duesseldorf', 'Leinfelden-Echterdingen', 'Eschborn'] }] },
                { name: 'Spain', states: [{ name: 'B', cities: ['Barcelona'] }] },
                { name: 'USA', states: [{ name: 'C', cities: ['Downers Grove'] }] },
                { name: 'Mexico', states: [{ name: 'D', cities: ['Puebla'] }] },           
            ]
        };
        this.changeCountry = this.changeCountry.bind(this);
        this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
        this.changeCity = this.changeCity.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.dropdownForm) {
            this.changeCountry();
            // this.changeState();
            // this.changeCity();
        }
    }

    changeCountry(event) {

        let countryVal = !event && this.props.dropdownForm ? this.props.dropdownForm.country : event.target.value;

        this.setState({ selectedCountry: countryVal });
        const result = this.state.countries.find(cntry => {
            return cntry.name === countryVal
        });
        result ? this.setState({ states: result.states }) : this.setState({ states: null });
        this.setState({ cities: null });
    }

    changeState(event) {

        let stateVal = !event && this.props.statePropSelected ? this.props.statePropSelected : event.target.value;

        this.setState({ selectedState: stateVal });
        const stats = this.state.countries.find(cntry => {
            return cntry.name === this.state.selectedCountry
        }).states;

        const result = stats.find(stat => stat.name === stateVal);

        result ? this.setState({ cities: result.cities }) : this.setState({ cities: null });
    }

    changeCity(e) {
        this.props.onChangeCity(e);
    }

    render() {

        let country = this.state.selectedCountry;
        let state = this.state.selectedState;

        return (
            <>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col md="4">
                        <Label htmlFor={this.props.countryProp} className="required">{this.props.countryProp}</Label>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs="12" md="8">
                        <Input type="select" name="country" id={this.props.countryProp} placeholder={this.props.countryProp} value={country} onChange={this.changeCountry}>
                            <option>Select Country</option>
                            {this.state.countries.map((e, key) => {
                                return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                            })}
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col md="4">
                        <Label htmlFor={this.props.stateProp} className="required">{this.props.stateProp}</Label>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs="12" md="8">
                        <Input type="select" name="state" id={this.props.stateProp} placeholder={this.props.stateProp} value={state} onChange={this.changeState}>
                            <option>Select State</option>
                            {
                                this.state.states ? this.state.states.map((e, key) => {
                                    return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                                }) : null
                            }
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col md="4">
                        <Label htmlFor={this.props.cityProp} className="required">{this.props.cityProp}</Label>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs="12" md="8">
                        <Input type="select" name="city" id={this.props.cityProp} placeholder={this.props.cityProp} onChange={this.changeCity}>
                            <option>Select City</option>
                            {
                                this.state.cities ? this.state.cities.map((e, key) => {
                                    return <option key={key}>{e}</option>;
                                }) : null
                            }
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
            </>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    dropdownForm: getDropdownData
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dropdown);
```

Selector:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const dropdown = (state) => {
    return state.profile.items.personal_details;
};

export const getDropdownData = createSelector(
    [dropdown],
    (data) => data
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case its better to use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) instead of componentDidMount. Since you are looking for an update of an specific property it's a good option.
Change this:

```
componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.dropdownForm) {
            this.changeCountry();
            // this.changeState();
            // this.changeCity();
        }
    }
```

To this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.dropdownForm && !this.state.countriesChanged) {
            this.changeCountry();
            this.setState({ countriesChanged: true });
            // this.changeState();
            // this.changeCity();
        }
    }
```

Edit note:

You may add a field in the state called "countriesUpdated" that works as a flag and set it to true when it execute that block.

Comment: I tried that but giving error `×
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that you need an stop condition. Because componentDidUpdate will be called every time the component re-renders. So when you check if dropdownForm exists, then you get the countries, then it will re-render the component with the countries and then it will execute componentDidMount again and so on.

Comment: yeah even if I remove condition same error is throwing

Comment: Okay. this is not throwing error but dropdown is not updating

Comment: Can you share a minimal working code to check what is happening?

Comment: I'v modified the post. Most of the code is in component only and a selector from which state I'm fetching. Also added the screenshot of country, state and city dropdown.

Comment: As I said in the post if I'm using setTimeout then sometime it is rendering country properly but that behaviour is not correct

Comment: It still not clear how to mount this Dropdown component, could you share how it's being called in the parent component and also the redux wrapper

Comment: ` <Dropdown
                            countryProp="Country"
                            stateProp="State"
                            cityProp="City"
                        >
                        </Dropdown>` just called like this from parent component

Comment: Can you fork this https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-matsumoto-hx38k and reproduce your issue there?